# In Crowd is it possible to grant a user to Jira and not to Confluence?

Tags: permissions, atlassian-crowd

If I have multiple Atlassian tools integrated with Crowd, i.e Jira, Confluence, Bamboo, etc., is it possible to grant a user access to Jira and not to Confluence or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by the use of Groups. So, for example, you could have a `jira-users` group and a `confluence-users` group. Some users maybe members of both but other users may only be members of one and not the other.

The [Managing Groups documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Managing+Groups) for Crowd should help setting up the groups and adding users to them.

[Specifying which Groups can access an Application](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Specifying+which+Groups+can+access+an+Application) details how to setup the restrictions you require per application.

Please note, that both these tasks require admin access to the Crowd Administration Console.